# t-sql to find repeated callers in customer care

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have situation where I need to find out the numbers which called in a customer care by same number within 2 days just for the current month. For example:

```
Number      dateTime
0987654321  2015-06-16 16:16:13.877
0987654321  2015-06-15 12:16:13.877
0789386834  2015-06-01 16:16:13.877
0789386834  2015-06-16 16:16:13.877
0987654321  2015-06-01 12:16:13.877
0123456789  2015-06-01 12:16:13.877
0123456789  2015-06-06 12:16:13.877
0123456789  2015-06-16 12:16:13.877
```

Here in this, I need to capture the number 0987654321 as he called on 15th and 16th (Less 2 days gap). Rest, 0123456789 and 0789386834 will not be included in the result as their calls were not made within 2 days. I am trying using CTE but it says memory out of exception.

PS: It has more than 2 millions of records.

Comment: First, post the CTE.  Second, it's possible your code is fine but you are simply running out of physical memory.  In that case, convert the code to use a temporary table (if possible) and see if the memory error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the expected result with this query:

```
-- dummy table   
DECLARE @tab TABLE
    (
        number VARCHAR(100),
        timeofcall DATETIME
    )

--insert sample values
    INSERT INTO @tab 
    VALUES
    ('0987654321','2015-06-16 16:16:13.877'),
    ('0987654321','2015-06-15 12:16:13.877'),
    ('0789386834','2015-06-01 16:16:13.877'),
    ('0789386834','2015-06-16 16:16:13.877'),
    ('0987654321','2015-06-01 12:16:13.877'),
    ('0123456789','2015-06-01 12:16:13.877'),
    ('0123456789','2015-06-06 12:16:13.877'),
    ('0123456789','2015-06-16 12:16:13.877')

--get records who are present in the table within 2 days
    SELECT  *
    FROM    @tab t
    WHERE   EXISTS(SELECT   TOP 1 1 
                    FROM    @tab t2 
                    WHERE   t2.number = t.number 
                            AND t2.timeofcall <> t.timeofcall
                            AND ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,t2.timeofcall,t.timeofcall)) <= 2)
```

Comment: the where clause inside the EXISTS() clause says (from 1st to 3rd): same number, different call, time between calls <= 2 days

Comment: I have 9150267 records in my table. The query is running since last 6 hours now. Is this normal? Any suggestions?

Comment: are there any indices on the table?

Comment: Only one, with Clustered index.

Comment: if there is any "ID" in your table , there should be a `unique clustered index` on it. what i would try is to create a `unique nonclustered index` on `number` and `timeofcall`. This should be unique too!?

Comment: Yes, they should be unique. The number column is is basically used as COALESCE(CalledFromNumber, CalledForNumber,'') . DO I need to put unique on this as well including TimeofCall?